# How to pass a matrix of constant values as an argument of a procedure call

Tags: delphi, multidimensional-array

I want to test a number of matrices by a procedure. Each matrix should be passsed as a matrix, something like:

```
type TMatrix = array of array of integer;
procedure test_kernel (mat: TMatrix);
....
test_kernel ([[1, 2], [1, 3]]); // <== does not compile
```

I cannot find the right syntax to do this correctly (tried with round brackets as well). Does anyone know how to pass a matrix of constant values as a procedure argument? Is it possible at all?

EDIT

As what I want is not possible I decided to use:

```
type TMatrix = array of integer;
procedure test_kernel (rows, cols: integer; mat: TMatrix);
....
test_kernel (2, 2, [1, 2, 
                    1, 3]);
```

So I get the illusion and readability of matrices. Thank you all!

Comment: I would recommend that you pass array parameters as `const` and that you do not declare `TMatrix` to be `array of Integer`. That's an array not a matrix. I would use an open array parameter: `const mat: array of Integer`.

Comment: I will use const. You are right about the naming, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There actually is a possiblity to do this if you use a slightly different declaration of TMatrix, but IMHO it doesn't increase the readability of the code:

```
type
  TVector = array of integer;
  TMatrix = array of TVector;
procedure test_kernel (mat: TMatrix);
....
test_kernel(TMatrix.Create(TVector.Create(1, 2), TVector.Create(1, 3)));
```

Comment: I did not know I could create arrays in this way. Thanks for pointing my attention to this. And I agree fully, it does not increase the readability of the code.

Comment: Would you happen to know since which version you can "instantiate" array types using `Create`?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do what you wish with constants or open arrays.  `TMatrix` is a dynamic array and you cannot have constants that are dynamic arrays. And a matrix is 2D but open arrays can't be nested. You cannot have an open array of open arrays. If this was just a vector, i.e. 1 dimensional, then you could indeed use open arrays. However, since you have a 2D matrix, open arrays can't help.

You will need to use a variable that is initialised at runtime. You can do this easily enough in an `initialization` section if you truly have a constant.

Comment: I hoped for some magic I'd overlooked :-) Thanks anyway. Pity I can't flag twice for a correct answer.